# How to save a line, that contains Extended ASCII characters, as a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm a trying to automate the daily process of "$git pull" by creating a batch script (to be executed in Windows PCs).

There would be two files:

- The batch script file, that will read line by line, from the second file, changing into the local repositories paths and executing "$ git pull";
- The .txt file, that would have, per line, one repository. Having no limited lines (repositories).

The problem is when in the .txt file is a line with a path with Extended ASCII characters, the variable with the string saves things like "├ü".

All the other paths work just fine, even the ones with spaces in the midle ("/path to/repository").

```
@echo off
set "repos=reposDIRs.txt"
echo %repos%

for /F "useback tokens=*" %%G in ("%repos%") do (
  echo %%G
  set "MyVar=%%G"
  cd MyVar
  git pull
  )

pause
```

I expected the variable %%G to hold "/pÁth/to/repository", but when I print it, the output is "/p├üth/to/repository"...

Comment: Well to start with, if you wanted to change directory to the line content, you'd need to reference a variable, `MyVar` isn't a variable, `%MyVar%` is. However, as you're setting the variable within the command block, you'd need to reference it using `!MyVar!` after enabling delayed expansion. That said, there is no need whatsoever for creating a variable, because the metavariable `%%G` already holds the line content. You would therefore use `CD /D "%%~G"` or `PushD "%%~G"`, _(with a subsequent `PopD` later)_. By the way, those characters are because you're using the wrong language/codepage.

Comment: Thank you @Compo for your fast answer.
I'll apply the suggested changes.

Comment: ```batch

@echo off

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set "repos=reposDIRs.txt"

echo %repos%

for /F "useback tokens=*" %%G in ("%repos%") do (

  CD /D "%%~G"

  git pull

  )

pause

```

I've applied the suggested changes and it still doesn't work...
@Compo! What do you mean when you say "you're using the wrong language/codepage"?